# InvalidCastException in Farseer's raycasting when trying to use the built-in explosion class?

Tags: xna, c#, farseer-physics-engine

I'm trying to create an explosion at the point that two entities collide, but whenever explosion.Activate() is called, it causes an InvalidCastException to be thrown in Raycast(), on the line that returns the callback.

`return callback(fixture, point, output.Normal, fraction);`

Is this a bug in Farseer, or am I doing something wrong? It doesn't appear to be a known issue.

Comment: Solved it, I was passing a non-integer value into UserData. The built-in explosion class relies on it being an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was passing a non-integer value into UserData. The built-in Explosion class relies on it being an integer.